# Universal vim-like keyboard shortcut for all program

Tags: linux, x11, shortcut

how can I write a program to implement vim feature in all other programs like this:

1. capture keystroke before all other program
2. decide whether it's in normal, insert or visual mode according to previous state
3. if it's in insert mode send exact keystroke to the focused window
4. if it's not read corresponding action from a config file and send that action ( that is another keystroke ) to the focused window

for example when I hit "j" if it's in normal mode it send "scroll down" shortcut and if it's in insert mode it send "j" character to the focused window or program

my questions are

is it possible ?
is there any similar program ?
how to capture keystroke before all other programs ?
how to send a keystroke to focused window ?
and actually what library do I need to use ?

thanks

Comment: look into actionscript and autohotkey

Comment: @Nomad101 Something tells me you're not a vim user. \@Raoof: this is hardly a suitable question for SO. It's overly broad, if anything. (Also, you're literally rambling of a list of questions in the end)

Comment: I was just stating a place to start to deal with capturing the keystrokes and deciding what to do with them, which is why I did not place an answer.

Comment: @sehe sorry maybe I couldn't say my point. maybe I should posted it in SU

Answer (score 0):

I kinda find my answer. with [i3wm](http://i3wm.org) and [xdotool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/xdotool.1.html) you can simulate vim-like behavior

in i3wm you can define different mode and assign same shortcut for different action like this :

```
mode "workspace" {
    bindsym j workspace prev
    bindsym h workspace prev
    bindsym k workspace next 
    bindsym l workspace next 
    bindsym Escape mode "default"
}
bindsym $mod+w mode "workspace"
```

add the above code to your .i3/cofig file , I used Mod4 (win key) for my $mod

now when you hit Mod4+w i3 goes to workspace mode and you can change workspace by hljk

here another example that actually didn't work for me but maybe it works for you

```
mode "vim" {
    bindsym --release j exec --no-startup-id xdotool key --clearmodifiers Down 
    bindsym --release k exec --no-startup-id xdotool key --clearmodifiers Up
    bindsym --release h exec --no-startup-id xdotool key --clearmodifiers Left 
    bindsym --release l exec --no-startup-id xdotool key --clearmodifiers Right
    bindsym Escape mode "default"
}
bindsym $mod+m mode "vim"
```